# Problems:Logging into mariadb Database on my local Server from my Mac in the same local network

Tags: php, server, mariadb, localhost

I try to connect on php to my Maria Database from my Mac to my server in the same network.

What I Tried:
I define  a user with the same name and password in the Maria DB like I am active on my Mac. 
myNameOnMac = myNameOnMysql
passowrd onMac = password onmysql

Then I logged into the database on my server without problems as root and 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mynameOnMac'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

OK!
 Then in php I try to get connection:
hp
$conn = new mysqli('myServerwithMariaDB', 'mynameOnMac', 'password onMac', 'myDatabase');

Result: Connection refused.
I tried a lot: 'mynameOnMac@192....', or 'mynameOnMac@%'
'mynameOnMac'@'%' gives a syntax error

What is wrong. Sometimes I get confusions with all the ''

Thank you for help

Comment: Is the mariadb server on another machne? Have you checked if that machine have the correct port (default: 3306) open for incoming connections?

Comment: Please give additional details about your current setup. Your are working with LAMP, Docker or individually installed packages?

Comment: the Maria DB is on another machine (old Mac mini with ubuntu). I have not open the port as I do not want that somebody can go from outside into the database.

Comment: A normal installation of Apache, Mariadb with "get install" - it is total old fashioned standard

Comment: _"I have not open the port as I do not want that somebody can go from outside into the database"_ - There's your issue. Your mac _is_ connecting from "outside into the database" since they are on different machines, so the old mac is most likely refusing all connections to it.

Comment: Now I've open the port 3306 but the result is the same. I think I do something wrong with user, password on Mac an database